# What address does the text section start?

Tags: c

I read in a book (can't recollect the name) that in a 32 bit system text section always starts at 0x0848000. But when I do `readelf -S example_executable` it does not reflect the same information. Why is that? Do other sections (bss,data,rodata etc) also start at fixed addresses? How can I find the alignment boundary for these sections?

Comment: many of these boundaries are randomized on modern operating systems because of Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR).

Comment: You probably mean 0x08048000, not 0x0848000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good explanation here of how Linux virtual memory works when allocating storage for a particular program.
[ua alberta - linux memory allocation](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html)

The designers of the compiler/linker tool chain need to allocate an arbitary address for particular blocks of memory. In order to make it easier for other components of the tool chain like debuggers and profilers they always allocatate the same block to the same addresses. The actual addresses chosen are completely arbitrary.

When the program is loaded the virtual address will be mapped to some random piece of free memory (this is mostly done in hardware). This mapping is done on a per process basis to several programs can address virtual address x'0848000' but be pointed at different "real" memory addresses.

Comment: The choice of address is not completely arbitrary; some choices are better than others. In particularly, putting the text segment at `0x60000000` or so would roughly halve the maximum possible `mmap` size the application could use...

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the implementation on the particular machine.For a linux machine the behaviour will be different than that from windows machine.
Note however that the virtual memory addresses need to start at some fixed address in order to make life easier for debuggers.However the real addresses will be different depending on the pages available in RAM.
If you look the output of readelf -S more carefully you will notice you will notice subtracting the offset from the address indeed gives you 0x0848000.
As i had mentioned earlier this **magic number 0x0848000** will depend on the type of executable format.
here is the output i get on my ubuntu 32 bit machine:

```
readelf -S ~/a.out
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x1130:

Section Headers:
[Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
[ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        08048134 000134 000013 00   A  0   0  1
[ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            08048148 000148 000020 00   A  0   0  4
[ 3] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            08048168 000168 000024 00   A  0   0  4
[ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0804818c 00018c 000020 04   A  5   0  4
[ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          080481ac 0001ac 000050 10   A  6   1  4
[ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          080481fc 0001fc 00004c 00   A  0   0  1
[ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          08048248 000248 00000a 02   A  5   0  2
[ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         08048254 000254 000020 00   A  6   1  4
[ 9] .rel.dyn          REL             08048274 000274 000008 08   A  5   0  4
[10] .rel.plt          REL             0804827c 00027c 000018 08   A  5  12  4
[11] .init             PROGBITS        08048294 000294 000030 00  AX  0   0  4
[12] .plt              PROGBITS        080482c4 0002c4 000040 04  AX  0   0  4
[13] .text             PROGBITS        08048310 000310 00018c 00  AX  0   0 16
[14] .fini             PROGBITS        0804849c 00049c 00001c 00  AX  0   0  4
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no consistent address between operating systems and architectures for the text section or any other section.  Additionally position independent code and address space layout randomizations make these values even inconsistent on the same machine for some systems.